# why is console.log(items); running twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
 Item.find()
    .then(function (items) {
      if (items.length === 0) {
        Item.insertMany(defaultItems)
        .then(function () {
          console.log("Successfully Saved");
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
      } else {
        res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", newListItems: items });
        console.log(items);
      }
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

just inserted defaultItems if no elements were present in database.
If elements were already present then simply print them on console.

Comment: There is no obvious reason why you're code should do that. Please create a runnable example in which we can experience this issue for ourselfs. Edit the question and use the snippet editor (`<>` icon) to create a runnable snippet.

Comment: Perhaps the parent code executes your code more than once. You may try to use `console.trace();` right after `console.log(items);` to get more details.

Eventually, you may try to debug this in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: How is this code called?  Is this awaited in addition to passing the callback?

Answer (score 1):

Until more information is provided about how this code is executed, it is difficult to determine the exact reason why console.log(items) is running twice.
However, you can place a console.log statement before the Item.find() call to check if the route is being called twice, or put a unique identifier inside the else block to confirm if the statement is being executed more than once.